# Spark 2.3 - How to read subdirectories with out asterisks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

```
String folder = "/Users/test/data/*/*";
sparkContext.textFile(folder, 1).toJavaRDD()
```

Is asterisks mandatory to read a folder. Yes, otherwise it is not reading files the subdirectories.

What if I get a folder which is having more subdirectories than the number of asterisks mentioned ? How to handle this scenario ?

For example:

1) `/Users/test/data/*/*`
This would work ONLY if I get data as /Users/test/data/folder1/file.txt

2)How to make this expression as **generic** ? It should still work if I get a folder as: `/Users/test/data/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4`

My input folder structure is not same all the time.

Is there anything exists in Spark to handle this kind of scenario ?

Comment: Are you passing the input folder?? For instance, are you passing what would replace */*?

Comment: i am passing /Users/test/data

Comment: @Kumar Did you solve it already?

Comment: not yet, can't find solution...

Answer (score 0):

On hadoop you could try `sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")`

But THB I don't think this will work in your case.

I would write a small function that returns the nested file structure as a list of paths and pass them to spark

Like:

```scala
val filePaths = List("rec1/subrec1.1/", "rec1/subrec1.2/", "rec1/subrec1.1/subsubrec1.1.1/",  "rec2/subrec2.1/")
val files = spark.read.text(filePaths: _*)
```